# How to fix Mechanize::ChunkedTerminationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I just received a Mechanize::ChunkedTerminationError, which I have never encountered before. All it says in the Documentation is:

> Raised when Mechanize detects the chunked transfer-encoding may be
>   incorrectly terminated.

Does anybody has an example of under what circumstances this happens and how I could go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.ignore_bad_chunking = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out the exact cause, but I had the same error and was able to avoid it by forcing the encoding, in my case to utf-8, before parsing the page contents.

```
page = agent.get(url)
page.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

I think this may happen when the contents of the page uses some character not supported by the character set specified by the web page.